# EF6 - Will SqlAzureExecutionStrategy work against regular Sql Server (non Azure)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6 ships with the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` which will retry on exceptions that are known to be possibly transient when working with SqlAzure.

Will this strategy also work for normal desktop Sql Server (non azure sql server) ?

Comment: Why would you need that, just use the Ado.net connection resiliency in .net 4.5.1 ?

Comment: Erik - Are they equivalent ?

Comment: No, the one for ado.net is general, not sql server or sql azure specific